# JSON encode to two variables PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have those values from my cookie:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:22:"302260 302250 302248";i:1;s:38:"Bruce Willis Jackie Chan Gary Oldman";}
```

I need this data to be separated like this:

```
$variable1 = [302260,302250,302248];
$variable2 = [Bruce Willis, Jackie Chan, Gary Oldman];
```

`json_decode` returned `NULL`, `unserialize` returned:

```
array ( 0 => '302260 302250 302248', 1 => 'Bruce Willis Jackie Chan Gary Oldman')
```

Now I don't know how to explode the names to `["Bruce Willis", "Jackie Chan", "Gary Oldman"]`.

Comment: You will have a problem with the actor names : if any of them is composed of more than three words, no algorithm will be able to separate them properly. I suggest manually adding the commas.

Comment: You should look into preg_match() and then use explode()

Answer (score 2):

You can try this with regex. Here is a simple example on how you could get it to work.

```
string = 'a:2:{i:0;s:20:"302260 302250 302248";i:1;s:36:"Bruce Willis Jackie Chan Gary Oldman";}';
$unserialized = unserialize($string);

// simple explode for the numbers
$variable1 = explode(" ", $unserialized[0]);

// here it gets harder, to get the result you could use some regex
// this regex will match a word+space+word. With preg_match_all you will get all those occurrences 
preg_match_all("/[\w]+\s[\w]+/", $unserialized[1], $matches);

$variable2 = $matches[0];

var_dump($variable1);
var_dump($variable2);
```

If the names will not always consist out of two words separated by space, this could get a lot harder.

In this case you may can check it against some Database, if you have one that consists those values. Lets say, those values come from some stored user data, you could use that as a check.

If the names can be written upper/lower-case with any kind of character, you might be totally out of luck.

Imagine data like `bOb lärson james baldwin jOhn franK frankenstein`. Could you see what names would belong together?

Even with a full name database, which consists all names ever, it will not be 100% accurate, as sometimes a surname can be used as a lastname as well.

Comment: I really appreciate the reference to bOb lärson james baldwin jOhn franK frankenstein. He's always been one of my favorite actors.

Comment: @Don'tPanic well yes, I agree. Always roll with the classics. So everyone know what I intend to mean with my examples.